# In tmux how does one specify a window that automatically follows you between sessions?

Tags: tmux, irc

I have irssi always running in my tmux session but often switch sessions. Is there a way to configure tmux to have a window follow me from session to session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `link-window` to pull a window from one session into another. I don't know the best way to automate this process, but manually, it's as simple as

```
link-window -s irssi:0
```

This assumes that you have `irssi` running in window 0 of a session called `irssi`, but you can change the argument to the `-s` option as necessary.